# How to display images from a directory as labels in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-label

I'm new to Python GUI using Tkinter, and I'm stuck with the following:

I'm trying to read some image files in a particular directory using Python's `os` module, and show them as labels of Tkinter in a single window. The images have an average size of `1990 x 1200`. So, I resized them using the Pillow library, and then packed every image to the window using a for loop.

But instead of showing the images, it's showing a blank window. I wrote the following code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Photo Gallery")
root.geometry("655x350")

for (root_, dirs, files) in os.walk("Wallpaper"):
    if files:
        for file_ in files:
            path = os.path.join("Wallpaper", file_)
            image_ = Image.open(path)
            n_image = image_.resize((100, 100))
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(n_image)
            img_label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
            img_label.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

That's a screenshot of the blank window:

[image: The image of the blank window.]

**Note:** I use Python 3.6.3 and Pillow 8.2.0.

Comment: Are you sure the images are getting picked?

Comment: I think there was a similar post answering this it mentioned throwaway variables or sth but I don't know if applicable in Your case (and I don't exactly remember how the post was called something along the lines of "image not showing up when created in a function PhotoImage")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Incorporating the hint from the comment of acw1668 (thanks for that!), the fix can be even more easier:

```py
for (root_, dirs, files) in os.walk("path/to/your/images"):
    if files:
        for file_ in files:
            path = os.path.join("path/to/your/images", file_)
            image_ = Image.open(path)
            n_image = image_.resize((100, 100))
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(n_image)
            img_label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
            img_label.photo = photo                             # <--
            img_label.pack()
```

---

I suppose it's an issue regarding the garbage collection of the images, cf. [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49916944/11089932). Simply keeping some references to the single `photo` variables did the trick for me:

```py
references = []                                                 # <--
for (root_, dirs, files) in os.walk("path/to/your/images"):
    if files:
        for file_ in files:
            path = os.path.join("path/to/your/images", file_)
            image_ = Image.open(path)
            n_image = image_.resize((100, 100))
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(n_image)
            img_label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
            img_label.pack()
            references.append(photo)                            # <--
```

That's some output:

[image: Output]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1
Pillow:        8.2.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Just use an attribute of the label is enough: `img_label.photo = photo`.  Then the list is not necessary.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for the hint! I edited that into my answer.