# How to display 'latest' captured image and then display it to a label in tkinter?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, label

I am trying to display 'latest' captured image for my project here in a label named captureLabel after I press the capture button as seen in the image below

[image: screenshot]

Appreciate the help..

Here is my full main.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import cv2
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
import time
import uuid

#setting title
gui = tk.Tk(className='yolov5')

#setting window size
width=1024
height=768
screenwidth = gui.winfo_screenwidth()
screenheight = gui.winfo_screenheight()
alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
gui.geometry(alignstr)
gui.resizable(width=False, height=False)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
IMAGES_PATH_CAPTURED = os.path.join('Captured')
label = 'image'

#functions
def captureButton_command():
    textLabel['text'] = "Capture button clicked.."
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    imgname = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH_CAPTURED, label+'.'+str(uuid.uuid1())+'.jpg')
    cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Image saved to {}".format(IMAGES_PATH_CAPTURED))
    
def exitButton_command():
    gui.destroy()
    
def video_stream():
    _, frame = cap.read()
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    cameraLabel.imgtk = imgtk
    cameraLabel.configure(image=imgtk)
    cameraLabel.after(1, video_stream) 

#Capture Button
captureButton=tk.Button(gui)
captureButton["bg"] = "#efefef"
ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=15)
captureButton["font"] = ft
captureButton["fg"] = "#000000"
captureButton["justify"] = "center"
captureButton["text"] = "Capture"
captureButton.place(x=10,y=220,width=150,height=50)
captureButton["command"] = captureButton_command

#Exit Button
exitButton=tk.Button(gui)
exitButton["bg"] = "#efefef"
ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=15)
exitButton["font"] = ft
exitButton["fg"] = "#000000"
exitButton["justify"] = "center"
exitButton["text"] = "Exit"
exitButton.place(x=170,y=220,width=150,height=50)
exitButton["command"] = exitButton_command

#Message on top
textLabel=tk.Label(gui)
ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=18)
textLabel["font"] = ft
textLabel["fg"] = "#333333"
textLabel["justify"] = "left"
textLabel["relief"] = "sunken"
textLabel["text"] = "Press capture to capture image"
textLabel.place(x=20,y=10,width=800,height=95)

#Camera Feed Label
cameraLabel=tk.Label(gui)
cameraLabel["text"] = "Camera Feed"
cameraLabel["borderwidth"] = "2px"
cameraLabel["relief"] = "solid"
cameraLabel.place(x=10,y=280,width=640,height=480)

#Captured Images Label
captureLabel = tk.Label(gui)
captureLabel["borderwidth"] = "2px"
captureLabel["relief"] = "solid"
captureLabel.place(x=720,y=110,width=300,height=300)

#Detected Images Label
detectedLabel = tk.Label(gui)
detectedLabel["borderwidth"] = "2px"
detectedLabel["relief"] = "solid"
detectedLabel.place(x=720,y=440,width=300,height=300)


            
#end
video_stream()
gui.mainloop()
```

I already tried the link [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67124121/how-to-display-images-from-a-directory-as-labels-in-tkinter) wherein it will save the image first in a folder and then reads the images but it seems to be showing only the images that are saved BEFORE running the application again and not displaying the latest images that I captured.

I was only expecting to display one image in the label provided with the border and displaying/replacing the result once I click the capture button.

Comment: Can you please respond my answer? I would like to know if my answer solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code sample seems to work fine.
For showing the captured frame in `captureLabel`, we may use the same code that is used in `video_stream()`, but using `captureLabel` instead of `cameraLabel`.

Example for updated: `def captureButton_command()`:

```python
def captureButton_command():
    textLabel['text'] = "Capture button clicked.."
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        imgname = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH_CAPTURED, label+'.'+str(uuid.uuid1())+'.jpg')
        cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
        #time.sleep(1)
        print("Image saved to {}".format(IMAGES_PATH_CAPTURED))
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        cv2image = cv2.resize(cv2image, [captureLabel.winfo_width(), captureLabel.winfo_height()], cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)  # Resize the captured frame to the size of the label.
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        captureLabel.imgtk = imgtk
        captureLabel.configure(image=imgtk)
```

Using `cv2.resize` is optional.

---

Make sure you have a folder named `Captured` in the "working folder".
The images are saved fine using names as:
`image.ed62ba02-f815-11ed-97a4-c86000dd9c4d.jpg`
`image.e75947ae-f815-11ed-8e4b-c86000dd9c4d.jpg`
...

---

Note:
It is recommended to verify that the value of `ret` is true after `ret, frame = cap.read()`

---

Updated code sample:

```python
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import cv2
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
import time
import uuid

#setting title
gui = tk.Tk(className='yolov5')

#setting window size
width=1024
height=768
screenwidth = gui.winfo_screenwidth()
screenheight = gui.winfo_screenheight()
alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
gui.geometry(alignstr)
gui.resizable(width=False, height=False)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
IMAGES_PATH_CAPTURED = os.path.join('Captured')
label = 'image'

#functions
def captureButton_command():
    textLabel['text'] = "Capture button clicked.."
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        imgname = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH_CAPTURED, label+'.'+str(uuid.uuid1())+'.jpg')
        cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
        #time.sleep(1)
        print("Image saved to {}".format(IMAGES_PATH_CAPTURED))
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        cv2image = cv2.resize(cv2image, [captureLabel.winfo_width(), captureLabel.winfo_height()], cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)  # Resize the captured frame to the size of the label.
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        captureLabel.imgtk = imgtk
        captureLabel.configure(image=imgtk)

    
def exitButton_command():
    gui.destroy()
    
def video_stream():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        cameraLabel.imgtk = imgtk
        cameraLabel.configure(image=imgtk)
        cameraLabel.after(1, video_stream)

       

#Capture Button
captureButton=tk.Button(gui)
captureButton["bg"] = "#efefef"
ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=15)
captureButton["font"] = ft
captureButton["fg"] = "#000000"
captureButton["justify"] = "center"
captureButton["text"] = "Capture"
captureButton.place(x=10,y=220,width=150,height=50)
captureButton["command"] = captureButton_command

#Exit Button
exitButton=tk.Button(gui)
exitButton["bg"] = "#efefef"
ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=15)
exitButton["font"] = ft
exitButton["fg"] = "#000000"
exitButton["justify"] = "center"
exitButton["text"] = "Exit"
exitButton.place(x=170,y=220,width=150,height=50)
exitButton["command"] = exitButton_command

#Message on top
textLabel=tk.Label(gui)
ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=18)
textLabel["font"] = ft
textLabel["fg"] = "#333333"
textLabel["justify"] = "left"
textLabel["relief"] = "sunken"
textLabel["text"] = "Press capture to capture image"
textLabel.place(x=20,y=10,width=800,height=95)

#Camera Feed Label
cameraLabel=tk.Label(gui)
cameraLabel["text"] = "Camera Feed"
cameraLabel["borderwidth"] = "2px"
cameraLabel["relief"] = "solid"
cameraLabel.place(x=10,y=280,width=640,height=480)

#Captured Images Label
captureLabel = tk.Label(gui)
captureLabel["borderwidth"] = "2px"
captureLabel["relief"] = "solid"
captureLabel.place(x=720,y=110,width=300,height=300)

#Detected Images Label
detectedLabel = tk.Label(gui)
detectedLabel["borderwidth"] = "2px"
detectedLabel["relief"] = "solid"
detectedLabel.place(x=720,y=440,width=300,height=300)


            
#end
video_stream()
gui.mainloop()
```

---

Sample output after pressing Capture button:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already been reading image from the camera every 1ms, you can use this image as the *captured image* instead of reading one from the camera again:

```py
def captureButton_command():
    textLabel['text'] = "Capture button clicked.."
    # get the saved image
    img = cameraLabel.img
    # save the image if required
    img.save(os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH_CAPTURED, label+'.'+str(uuid.uuid1())+'.png'))
    print("Image saved to {}".format(IMAGES_PATH_CAPTURED))
    # resize the image to fit the size of captureLabel
    img.thumbnail((300, 300))
    # show the image in captureLabel
    captureLabel.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    captureLabel.config(image=captureLabel.image)

...

def video_stream():
    _, frame = cap.read()
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    cameraLabel.img = img      ### save the image
    cameraLabel.imgtk = imgtk
    cameraLabel.configure(image=imgtk)
    cameraLabel.after(1, video_stream)
```